# Git for Windows, setting GIT_SSH to a shell file causes causes "error: cannot spawn <path>: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, git, shell, batch-file, ssh

On `Windows 10`, using [`Git-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/Git-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.exe), if I do:

```
set GIT_SSH=D:\ssh.sh
```

I get:

```
error: cannot spawn D:\ssh.sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

But if I instead do:

```
set GIT_SSH=D:\ssh.exe
```

or:

```
set GIT_SSH=D:\ssh.bat
```

everything works as intended.

My `PATHEXT`:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.sh
```

A registry file that has been applied:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\bash.exe]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\bash.exe\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\bash.exe\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\bash.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\sdk\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\sh.exe]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\sh.exe\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\sh.exe\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\sh.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\sdk\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sh_auto_file]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sh_auto_file\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sh_auto_file\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sh_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\sdk\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sh_auto_file\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sh]
@="sh_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sh\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,36,\
  00,38,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sh\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sh\shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""
```

The result of these is that if I open up `cmd` and enter:

```
D:\ssh.sh
```

or even:

```
D:\ssh
```

the script is executed.

But git refuses to use the shell script, but is content to use `.exe` files and `.bat` files.

Why is this? Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: `cmd` is running shell scripts suddenly?  Or *git bash* is running shell scripts?

Comment: You can invoke `batch` scripts from `cmd`, just like you can invoke `python` scripts or `shell` scripts for that matter - it makes no difference. When `cmd` encounters a batch script, it knows how to handle it... the registry file + the `PATHEXT` I've provided is mostly what you need to handle `shell` files, except for the `shebang` (`#!`) part.

Comment: It does make a difference - because you cannot - *by default* - invoke a shell script by running `D:\ssh.sh`.  So I'm curious as to whether you set up a handler for `.sh` files?

Comment: Yes, that is what the registry stuff + the PATHEXT does. Adding `.sh` to PATHEXT makes it so that you can invoke `kaboom.sh` as `kaboom` in `cmd`. The `sh_auto_file` file part in the registry stuff makes it so that the `sh` program that is provided by `Git for Windows` handles `.sh` scripts.

Comment: You can do the same for `python` and perhaps even a generalized shebang handler for all files that you somehow deem executable (Windows permissions are kinda flawed...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some totally unexplained reason, I can verify that NOW it works in both `cmd` and `git bash` whilst it didn't before.

Now on to creating a git-repo preprocessor for ssh so multi-account users have it easier.